VBA filter return 0 rows, how to detect
I have this VBA code to dynamically delete rows from tables, but i am unable to detect when the filter made by my code returns 0 rows, I would like you to skip the Delete step when this happens, as this would mean that there are no rows to be deleted, however, it is giving me an error in the Delete step, here is my code, i tried using If Not rngFiltro Is Nothing but it gives me an error, here is my code:
Sub EXC_L(lo As ListObject, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim colFornecedor As ListColumn
    Dim rngFiltro As Range

    With ws
        lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Set colFornecedor = lo.ListColumns("Fornecedor")
        colFornecedor.Range.AutoFilter Field:=colFornecedor.Index, Criteria1:=""
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngFiltro = colFornecedor.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not rngFiltro Is Nothing Then
            rngFiltro.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
End Sub

The error message is:

"delete method of range class failed"


Delete Rows When Blank in Specified Column of Excel Table (ListObject)
Issues

colFornecedor.Range is a single column. You cannot filter a single column by any other (colFornecedor.Index) field than 1.

If you filter in this way (with the 1), you cannot reference the entire filtered table rows so easily (you need the slow Intersect).

When dealing with an Excel table, IMO, it is incorrect (at least unnecessary) to go outside its rows and columns e.g. using rngFiltro.EntireRow i.e. you want to keep anything outside the table intact.

Either pass Worksheet or ListObject. One can usually be referenced using the other e.g.:
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = lo.Range.Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)

You're not utilizing the ws variable in any way so your With statement is simply redundant as is passing the worksheet.


An Improvement
Sub DeleteBlankSupplierRows( _
        ByVal lo As ListObject, _
        Optional ByVal DisplayMessages As Boolean = False)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Blank Supplier Rows"
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const LIST_COLUMN_NAME As String = "Fornecedor"
    Const COLUMN_CRITERION As String = ""
    
    ' Declare a variable to hold the filtered rows (range object).
    Dim frg As Range
    
    ' Filter the table.
    With lo
        ' Clear table filters.
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        ' Filter.
        .Range.AutoFilter _
            Field:=.ListColumns(LIST_COLUMN_NAME).Index, _
            Criteria1:=COLUMN_CRITERION
        ' Reference the filtered rows.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set frg = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Clear table filters.
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
        
    ' Check if no filtered rows.
    If frg Is Nothing Then
        If DisplayMessages Then
            MsgBox "No blank Supplier rows found!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Delete filtered rows.
    frg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        
    ' Inform.
    If DisplayMessages Then
        MsgBox "Blank Supplier rows deleted.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
        
End Sub

More Dynamic
Calling Procedure (Example)
Sub DeleteBlankSupplierRows()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    DeleteRows lo, "Fornecedor", "", True
    
End Sub

The Called Procedure (Method)
Sub DeleteRows( _
        ByVal lo As ListObject, _
        ByVal ListColumnName As String, _
        ByVal Criterion As String, _
        Optional ByVal DisplayMessages As Boolean = False)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Rows"
    
    ' Declare a variable to hold the filtered rows (range object).
    Dim frg As Range
    
    ' Filter the table.
    With lo
        ' Clear table filters.
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        ' Filter.
        .Range.AutoFilter _
            Field:=.ListColumns(ListColumnName).Index, _
            Criteria1:=Criterion
        ' Reference the filtered rows.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set frg = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Clear table filters.
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
        
    ' Check if no filtered rows.
    If frg Is Nothing Then
        If DisplayMessages Then
            MsgBox "No cells equal to """ & Criterion & """ in column """ _
                & ListColumnName & """ of table """ & lo.Name & """ found!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Delete filtered rows.
    frg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        
    ' Inform.
    If DisplayMessages Then
        MsgBox "Deleted rows where cells were equal to """ & Criterion _
            & """ in column """ & ListColumnName & """ of table """ _
            & lo.Name & """.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
        
End Sub

